# How to keep a list static in Python?

Tags: python, list, addition

Alright, so I have a long list of numbers, like so:

```
q = [3495790.0, 2386479.0, 2398462.0]
```

and so on and so on about 300 times. I want to get another version of this list with all the numbers added by 1800, while retaining the original list for comparison purposes. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
q1 = [x + 1800 for x in q]
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I always forget about list comprehensions.

Answer (score 3):

```
q2 = [x + 1800.0 for x in q]
```

will create a new list with 1800 added to each entry.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can just assign the result of a list comprehension to another list:

```
# Given:
q = [3495790.0, 2386479.0, 2398462.0]

# You could do...
r = [x + 1800 for x in q]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be accurate, this is the best way:

```
q2 = [x + 1800.0 for x in q]
```

But if you're feeling creative, you can also use a lambda with map (and by creative, I mean annoying):

```
q2 = map(lambda a: 1800.0 + a, q)
```

And, of course, there is the slow and non-pythonic

```
q2 = []
for i in q:
   q2.append(i)
```